# How can i fix my raspberry pi 4 after high voltage input?

Tags: raspberry-pi

Accidently i gave my pi high voltage (10V 1.8 amps) after that there is no video output. Im connecting my pi to monitor(not tv monitor) and the monitor says there is no video output. I've tried with new sd card and change config.txt it havent worked. I need full circuit datasheet for raspberry pi4 model B for check the all routes. Im new in this do you guys know another solution other than software problems cuz i think my problem is not software problem

Comment: *do you guys know another solution* - Buy a new one.

Comment: Do you see a led (the green ?) blinking at boot ? If not ... sorry ...

Comment: You have released the magic smoke.  It is a 5V device and you have applied 10V, you know the answer, now you have to accept it.

Comment: how would a full schematic help you?

Comment: When i put in the sd card green light is on, when i pull the sd card green light blinking 4 times

Answer (score 2):

It is highly probable that your RPi is irretrievably destroyed. Delicate semiconductors (MCUs, SOCs etc.) are **very** sensitive to voltage spikes (Even spikes as small as a few hundred millivolts can destroy those chips, let alone double the rated input voltage.)

Also you will probably not find the full schematic of RPi, because it is not public.